# Too many values to unpack...but there aren't

Tags: python, dictionary

So url is a dictionary, I am iterating over its keys. Then for each key, I am trying to unpack the values in that dictionary.

```
for key in url:
    print len(url[key])
    for val, date in url[key]:
        print val, date
```

The dictionary is in a format like this:

url[key] = (['value','value2','value3'],'date')

Where a key corresponds to a tuple of length 2. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insertCIF.py", line 10, in <module>
    for val, date in url[key]:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Which is funny because that 2 at the top is the result of the print length statement. So how am I trying to unpack too many values, when I am trying to unpack 2 values, and I verified that the length of the tuple is indeed 2?

I know I can do url.items or iteritems as a workaround (and it does work) but this issue has me curious and I can't figure it out or troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are trying to iterate over the value of `url[key]` using `for` loop. In order to assign the values, instead you should be doing just:

```
val, date = url[key]:
```

Comment: I figured it out as soon as I posted it.  I'll accept this as the answer as soon as SO lets me. Wow, I feel stupid...

Answer (score 1):

First off, what you really want is this:

```
val, date = url[key]
```

What you're doing, is loop over a tuple, while unpacking each element into `val, date`.

Looping over `url[key]` the way you did, will take the first element of url[key] ´(which is your list) and unpack it into `val, date`, which has not enough variables (2) for your list (4 items).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out as soon as I posted it. The other guy answered about 14 seconds before you so I'm accepting his answer. I feel stupid lol, must need coffee. Thanks again ;-)